# Need to use double code and pass variable in sed command

Tags: bash, unix

Searching pattern and displaying with SED which have double code (") and variable need to pass.

Actual log is:

```
<confirmation ID="123456-109" status>
```

Want to Print 109

This is with actual sed command which worked :

```
sed -n 's%.*confirmation="123456-\(.*\)" status.*%\%p' /tmp/log
```

output: 109

But when I tried use this in script where passing 123456 as variable it is not working.

```
req_data=`sed -n 's%.*confirmation="$variable-\(.*\)" status.*%\%p' /tmp/log`
```

When I run in Script is is not giving me any output.

I am expecting output: 109

Answer (score 0):

Execute a `command` and assign its output to variable `res` as `res="$(command)"`.

You need to used `sed -E` to make parenthesis work for grouping (or in normal mode, you have to escape each parenthesis). (note that `-E` option of `sed` is not part of the `posix` standard)

Also, as stated in the comments, variables are not expanded/interpolated inside single quotes. If you are in a single quoted block, terminate that before the variable and start a different block after the variable.

Following should addresses all the above and should solve your problem.

```
req_data="$(sed -En 's%.*confirmation ID=\\"'$variable'-(.+)\\" status.*%\1%p' /tmp/log)"
```